# Reporting Services - finding the current month through a expression

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I would like to have a default value, that is the current year-month. Today my expression looks like this:

```
[Date Product Confirmed].[Date].[Yearmd].&[2013-03]
```

I would, or course, like to make the last part dynamic: `&[2013-03]`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
="[Date Product Confirmed].[Date].[Yearmd].&[" & Cstr(Format(now(),"yyyy-MM")) &"]"
```

Comment: That worked, and a quite simple solution as well. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current year and month like that

```
=Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM")
```

Basically i getting the current date using `Now()`
and then i am formatting it yo be YYYY-MM

Comment: That is a very straightforward method, i like it. Could you perhaps also help me with how to implement it in the rest of the expression? I do have to get more accustomed to visual basic in the near future, but the deadline for this report is coming up fast.